# Send multiple parameter and pdf file to create methode with HttpClient & PostAsync

Tags: c#

i'd like to consume webservice that create customer
i'd like send different parameters and pdf file

```
    method : initCustumer
@return : { id_customer : [INT] }
@params :
    - login : [STRING]
    - age: [INT] 
    - date_create : [DATE] 
    - raison_sociale[] : [STRING] 
    - fiche : [FILE] //pdf file
```

in my code that call webservice

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.pdf");
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StringContent("login"), "login");
        content.Add(new StringContent("age"), "20");
        content.Add(new StringContent("date_create"), DateTime.Now.ToString());
        content.Add(new StringContent("raison_sociale"), "raison_sociale");
        content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "fiche", "fiche.pdf");
        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:67/api/customer?method=initCustomer", content).Result;
        var input = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

i must to return the idcustomer

thanks

Comment: Which bit doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post what the issue is? It seems to me that you haven't attempted to write the service yet.